# Visualise topics from BERTopic

Tags: python, machine-learning, bert-language-model

I am using `TOPIC_MODEL.visualize_topics()` for visualising my topics on the graph.
This is the example:

[image]

My question is, how to see more than 5 words when I hover over blob topics on the graph?

Answer (score 0):

This value of visualizing `5-keywords` is hard-coded. So, you won't be able to pass as parameter. Check out the code here: https://github.com/MaartenGr/BERTopic/blob/1ee8141d65063a37f6ee3fd56b30e3f9e2f43d6e/bertopic/plotting/_topics.py#L66

[image: top-5 words BERTopic visualization]

If you really want to hack this, you can fork a repository and change the value or pass as parameter for your use. The file tree from original source is something like below:

```
BERTopic v0.14.0
BERTopic/bertopic/plotting/_topics.py (Line #66)
```

Answer (score 0):

BerTopic merely makes few calls to existing APIs, so I advise to **repeat and adapt the few steps that BerTopic takes** when generating the plot. We gain lots of flexibility with little code, plus educatation on how it works:

```py
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy as sch
from bertopic._utils import validate_distance_matrix
import plotly.figure_factory as ff


embeddings = topic_model.c_tf_idf_ # (N_TOPICS,N_WORDS)
distance_fn = lambda x: 1 - cosine_similarity(x)
distance_function_viz = lambda x: validate_distance_matrix(distance_fn(x), embeddings.shape[0])
fig = ff.create_dendrogram(embeddings,
                            orientation=orientation,
                            distfun=distance_function_viz,
                            linkagefun=linkage_function,
                            hovertext=annotations,
                            color_threshold=color_threshold)
axis= "yaxis"

def get_topic_label(idx):
    return str(idx)+"_"+"_".join(k for (k,v) in topic_model.get_topic(int(idx))[:5])

fig.update_layout(
    height=200 + (15 * embeddings.shape[0]),
    width = 1200,
    yaxis=dict(tickmode="array",ticktext=list(map(get_topic_label, fig.layout[axis]["ticktext"])))
)
fig
```

[image]